# run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)' in Excel VBScript app affects different users differently

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, userform, varchar

This triggers when the VBScript (in an excel based app) attempts to complete a userform and insert data into a table in a SQL database.

This affects only one user, it works fine for everyone else.

The error message reads 'the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

I've checked for quote marks accidentally being included in date fields. I've checked all settings in the user's excel config/Trust Centre. I've compared everything visible in the userform to a user who doesn't have this problem.

All users are accessing the same file that contains the VBScript so there can't be any differences in the code, it must be something to do with either the way it's evaluated by different user's machines or access permissions.

I've made sure all external connections are enabled in the user's excel config, matching the config of a user that can use the userform fine. I've tested on another user's machine by intentionally inserting text strings in quotes into date fields to try to reproduce the bug - it doesn't.

Comment: Check the Windows Regional settings, especially the Short Date and Long Date setting.

Comment: No, this is the same across users as well. Thanks though.

Comment: Perhaps check the keyboard (or default font?) settings for a character set that is different than you expect.

Comment: To help you get some traction with this question, I'd suggest you might want to change the question tags to add 'sql' (and so get some SQL expertise looking at this for you)? Also you should clarify VBA vs VBScript as they are not the same thing (though have similarities) ... if you edit the code within (for example) Excel then it is VBA (so correct the title and question body) ... if you edit the code within a .vbs file it is VBScript (and so change the 'vba' tag to 'vbscript').